# How does functional completeness relate to expressiveness in higher-order logics?

Tags: propositional-calculus, functional-completeness

In first-order logic, the notion of functional completeness is well-defined. But in higher-order logics, where we can quantify over predicates and not just individuals, the notion of functional completeness may be more complex.